# std::includes работает неправильно

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Почему программа выводит 0? В описании функции сказано Returns true if the sorted range [first1,last1) contains all the elements in the sorted range [first2,last2).http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/includes/. Но a содержит все элементы из b (1 и 2)

```
std::vector a{1, 2};
std::vector b{1, 2, 1, 2};

std::cout << std::includes(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
```

Comment: Требование `sorted range` у вас явно не соблюдено.

Comment: @VTT то есть они УЖЕ должны быть отсортированы на вход алгоритму? я думал, что это алгоритм делает

Comment: @VTT не, я попробовал для {1,1,2,2} - тоже не работает!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::vector<int> a{1, 2}; // тут вы забыли аргумент шаблона
std::vector<int> b{1, 2, 1, 2};
```

Поменяйте местами  обьекты, и все заработает

```
std::swap(a, b);
std::cout << std::includes(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
```

если `b` является подмножеством  `a`, то получите положительный результат

Comment: Аргумент шаблона в C++17 выводится из инициализатора.

Comment: У меня нет  такого компилятора, но спасибо

Comment: И все же допишите необходимость сортировки... А то ведь если возьмете `b{2,2,1,1}` - может и не получиться :)

Answer (score 3):

Здесь по сути проверяется, входит ли диапазон полностью в другой диапазон, а не вычисляется разность множеств. Поэтому одинаковые элементы вполне допустимы (как в мультимножестве), и диапазона `a` явно не хватает для **включения** диапазона `b`.

А вот наоборот - вполне: проверьте сами

```
std::cout << std::includes(b.begin(), b.end(), a.begin(), a.end());
```

но не забудьте отсортировать :)

Другими словами, `a` является подмножеством `b`, но `b` не является подмножеством `a` - хотя бы потому, что в нем больше элементов :)

Comment: Неее,  std::includes не требует сортировки....

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Returns true if the **sorted** range [first2, last2) is a subsequence of the **sorted** range [first1, last1). (A subsequence need not be contiguous.) - отсюда: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes

Comment: не знаю честно, потому что по стандарту нужна сортировка, но у меня и без сортировки он работал(фокус). Нужно проверять в чем дело...