# Поведение и работа алгоритма std::includes

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Недавно вопрос прозвучал про этот алгоритм. По стандарту он принимает отсортированные последовательности, но у меня всегда выдавал правильный результат и  для неотсортированных множеств. Вот, например:

```
std::vector<int> a{1, 2, 5, 3, 11, 23, 12, 6};
std::vector<int> b{5, 3, 11};
if (std::includes(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end()))
    cout << b.back();  // вывод 11
```

И, на всякий случай, ссылка на стандарт:  https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes
Думаю, просто алгоритм быстрее работает для сортированных множеств, а не сортирует  неотсортированные (или просто не требуется сортировка?).  Пока не разобрался, хотелось бы получить от вас помощь(каков ваш ответ?...)  Просто, чисто логично, сортировка тут не нужна вовсе...

Comment: сортировка требуется. Просто в этом случае повезло что значащая часть (до 23 была отсортированна) (содержала сегмент 5-3-11 именно в таком порядке а то 5 были числа меньше)

Comment: Вопрос связан с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/921770/317064) вопросом

Comment: @cpp questions, я в вопросе уже отметил, что связан. Не затрудняйтесь повторять

Comment: @ARHovsepyan так чтобы система поняла, что связан, нужно ссылку дать на него. Тогда справа в "Связанные" появится. Добавьте ссылку в вопрос и я удалю, если не хотите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас слишком хорошая последовательность выбрана... Попробуйте на

```
std::vector<int> a{1, 2, 5, 3, 23, 11, 12, 6};
```

Взгляните на примерную реализацию алгоритма по указанной вами ссылке, и все должно стать понятно, почему это так.

По законам логики из ложных посылок может вытекать как ложь, так и истина, так что верный результат еще не говорит о том, что он будет всегда :( А вот хоть один ложный показывает, что исходные посылки - ложны.

Comment: Я уже запутался, потом посмотрю(перекур)

Answer (score 5):

> но у меня всегда выдавал правильный результат и для неотсортированных множеств

Вы что-то выдумываете. Поведение алгоритма `std::includes` на неупорядоченных последовательностях не определено, т.е. он *вообще не работает* на неупорядоченных последовательностях. Ваше "у меня всегда выдавал правильный результат" - это просто случайность (в которую, к тому же, трудно поверить).

> Просто, чисто логично, сортировка тут не нужна вовсе

Отнюдь. Стандартная функция `std::includes` и остальные функции этой группы (`std::set_difference`, `std::set_union` и т.д.) для того и заведены, чтобы реализовать теоретико-множественные операции через хрестоматийный алгоритм синхронного прохода по двум отсортированным последовательностям. Без упорядоченности последовательностей эти алгоритмы не имеют смысла.

Comment: [это просто случайность] Я сам знал человека, который во времена MS DOS системные дискеты создавал командой copy, а не командой sys. И у него все работало. И он был свято уверен, что так и надо делать. А разгадка была проста - он брал дискеты на которых когда-то была система, удалял все файлы и копировал io.sys, msdos.sys и command.com, которые падали на нужное место в начале тома. boot сектор был прописан, так что все начинало работать. Вот такое счастье бывает у людей.

Comment: @pepsicoca1,  мой случай связан с тем, что я пишу программы чисто ради любопытства , да и  сам алгоритм не часто используемый.  Но такое совпадение я не считаю удачей, а совсем наоборот.  Еслибы я получал неправильный результат, то  не сложилось бы ошибочное мнение...

Comment: @AnT, как вы считаете, какой интерес я должен приследовать, чтобы выдумывать?   Бывало, использовал, не  стал разбираться, и ошибочное мнение превратилось в убежденность. Спасибо  что помогли и подсказали.